# How do I create a helper for Jasmine/Angular to combine multiple beforeEach's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I keep repeating some code in my spec file that injects a template and then compiles it.  I extracted this code into a helper function to keep things DRY.  I believe the problem is in trying to place to `beforeEach`'s in a helper function.  Here is the piece of my code that I am trying to abstract into a function:

```
  beforeEach(module('app/views/header.html'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
    template = $templateCache.get('app/views/header.html');
    $templateCache.put('views/header.html', template);
    var directive = angular.element('<clinical-header></clinical-header>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));
```

Here is the helper function that I created:

```
var setupTemplate = function(templateName, element) {
  beforeEach(module('app/views/' + templateName));
  beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
    var template = $templateCache.get('app/views/' + templateName);
    $templateCache.put('views/' + templateName, template);
    var directive = angular.element(element);
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));
```

And now this is the call to the helper function:

```
setupTemplate('header.html', '<clinical-header></clinical-header>');
```

At the end of my helper function, everything looks good, but when I jump to my `it` block, everything is undefined.  Can I extract multiple `beforeEach`'s?  What is the right way to do this?  Also, where is the proper place to put jasmine helper functions and how is that done?

Answer (score 16):

You can create global beforeEach() functions by writing them outside the context of a specific describe function.
You should create a spec-helper.js class with these function and load it thru Karma config.

Note that the beforeEach functions will execute before any it function you are running (as they are global).

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/vVZmx/) to demonstrate, however the key with Karma is to add the file to the configuration so it is loaded by the browser.

Spec Helper:

```
var myGlobal;
beforeEach(function() {
    // This will run before any it function.
    // Resetting a global state so the change in this function is testable
   myGlobal = 10
});
```

Test Suite:

```
describe('first suite', function(){
   it('is a test', function(){
     expect(myGlobal).toBe(10);
     // Reset the value to show that beforeEach is executed for each it function
     myGlobal = 20;
     expect(myGlobal).toBe(20);
  });

  it('is another test', function($location){
     expect(myGlobal).toBe(10);
     myGlobal = 20;
     expect(myGlobal).toBe(20);
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem if you want to only run the code for a subset of tests, where the tests are in separate files.

Comment: You're right. This runs for all tests, regardless of their file

Comment: I have a very similar situation in my project. I wrapped my global `beforeEach` calls inside a function, and just call that function at the top of my `describe` block for any test suites which need it.

Comment: How do you add the file to your Karma config?  When I tried it, it fails horribly with exceptions on every test: "Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!"

Comment: @Isiden you can't call the angular.mock.module function after calling inject. You must complete all calls to module() before the first call to inject() so if your global beforeEach calls inject() you can't call module() in your tests, i.e. - don't inject() in the global beforeEach